# Finding clusters of similar variables in a time series

Tags: clustering

What methods are appropriate to identify groups of similar variables in a time series?  For example, in the following dummy dataset, I'd like to identify (a,b,c) and (d,e) as clusters of similar variables.

```
library(reshape)
library(ggplot2)
a <- c(1,2,3,2,1)
b <- jitter(a, 2)
c <- jitter(a, 2)
d <- c(5,4,3.5,4,5)
e <- jitter(d, 2)
f <- c(1,1,1,2,2.2)
date <- as.Date(c('2016-02-03', '2016-03-01', '2016-04-04', '2016-05-03', '2016-06-01'))
df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,f, date)
ggplot(melt(df, id.vars = 'date'), aes(date, value, color=variable)) + geom_point() + geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Could you describe what you mean by "similar" more precisely?  The illustration suggests many possible definitions, which could be measured variously by correlation, mean squared differences, maximum absolute differences, and many more.

Comment: Good question.  Currently, I am using [Lin's concordance correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concordance_correlation_coefficient) as a measure of similarity.   I have calculated a pairwise similarity matrix using this statistic.  So, another way of asking my question might just be:  How can I cluster the elements of a pairwise similarity matrix?  But I thought I'd make the question general to see if I might get suggestions I hadn't considered.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote?  [SO guidelines say](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down): `Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post...`  Really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example, hierarchical clustering should just work.

Time series get painful once you have different rate, resolution, multiple variables, seasonality, and all that.

Comment: Thanks -- this is also the conclusion I reached.  I settled for hierarchical clustering with average linkage strategy, based on a distance matrix created by subtracting and normalizing the correlation matrix (calculated as described in the comments above.)  It seems to be working well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know too much about the method, but perhaps you could consider [latent class growth analysis?](http://ww.statmodel2.com/download/JungWickramaLCGALGMM.pdf) The linked paper, Jung & Wickrama (2008), is from a journal that aims to be accessible, so I thought it would be a good resource.